# PHP Displaying CSV File in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, csv

Greeting Experts,

I have a php script that queries our db and spits out a csv file in a browser.  This work greate in FireFox, Safari, and Chrome.  It does not work in Internet Explorer, which is the default browser in our building (sigh).  I cannot post the url as it is a protected site and wouldn't do you any good.

In IE I get two popup windows when I click the linke to this report:

1) Unable to download downloads.html from .
Unable to open this Internet Site.  The request site is either unavailable or cannot be found Please try again later.

2) a downloads % info window:
Getting File Information:
downloads.html from 
Estimated time left:
Download to:
Transfer rate:
all these are empty.

So, I have an page, downloads.html trying to produce a CSV file.  Not sure what is bombing here as far as IE goes.  Are there different headers I can try?  I haven't seen any in my searching.

Thanks for any tips...

Here is my function that prints out the data:

```
# $data is array of data from database
function render_excel($data) {
  # headers for browsers
  header("Content-type: text/csv");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");

  # column headers
  $column_headers = "Filename, Link to File, Details, Unique Viewers\n";
  $rows = '';
  foreach($data as $foo => $arr){   
    $rows .= $arr['filename'].",";
    $rows .= $arr['resource_url'].",";
    $rows .= $arr['detail_url'].",";
    $rows .= $arr['distinct_views']."\n";
  }
  print $column_headers;
  print $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems I think. First is that you need quotes around the filename and second is that you need to add a `Content-Length` header to show download times.

```
//1
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.csv\"");

//2
header("Content-Length: " . (strlen($column_headers.$rows)));
```

Keep in mind that the length might be different if you have other code on your page.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, but no luck with those changes.  I even tried header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
  with no luck

Comment: Then I guess Adrian is right and IE is just not expecting dynamic content with an `HTML` extention.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, getting this to work with IE - particularly older versions of IE - required using mod_rewrite to redirect a URL with the correct file extension (e.g. download/file.csv) to the PHP file that generates the CSV output. IE for some reason prefers the URL file extension over the content-type and content-disposition headers.